# How to check in PHP if variable is set and check if two values match set variable?

Tags: php, get, isset

I know that is basic question, but i can't figure out how to test if `$_GET['zanr']` contains `''` or `'sve'` to do other stuff in my script...i try using this code but it only checks `''` and `'sve'` is ignored...so how to check if `'zanr'` contains `''` or `'sve'` do stuff a else do stuff b?

```
if (isset($_GET['zanr']) === '' || isset($_GET['zanr']) === 'sve'){
  echo "zanr = '' or 'sve'";
} else {
  echo "zanr contains other values...";
}
```

I also try using ?? but no success...thanks.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php `isset()` returns a bool value. "_Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your goal is to check if your $_GET is empty, use PHP built in function: [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). And your second statement is wrong because [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is returning a boolean and therefore you're not validating the string itself. So be sure to remove `isset()` and just compare if `$_GET['zanr']` has your specific string.

Use this:

```
if (empty($_GET['zanr']) || $_GET['zanr'] == 'sve'){
    echo "zanr = '' or 'sve'";
} else {
    echo "zanr contains other values...";
}
```

Comment: thanks..this is very good answer..now it works..empty was solution and double ==...i lost one hour of testing why it does not work..your code works...i will accept answer in 7minutes.

Comment: @IgorPetev this solution will not work, if by some reasons $_GET does not have 'zanr' key; this will return undefined index warning in that case and code will break

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
if (isset($_GET['zanr']) && ($_GET['zanr'] == '' || $_GET['zanr'] == 'sve')){
  echo "zanr = '' or 'sve'";
} else {
  echo "zanr contains other values...";
}
```